# How do I check if my editText field is empty and make it go to a new activity with a Button?

Tags: java, android

I have made this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton ourButton;
private EditText operand1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find Views by IDs :
    ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

    String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString().trim();
    if(ed_text.isEmpty() || ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null)
    {
        ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The problem is that if I pressed the button with or without entering anything in the field, it will say :

> You did not enter a username

And the next activity will not work neither.

How do I make the button to move the user into the next activity while making sure he inputed a name?

Comment: `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

Comment: You'll have to do the check inside the `onClick(...)` method.

Comment: First learn about interface and callback methods. Then learn about activity life cycle. I think you didn't know those things.

Comment: Did you try to do this ? Try it first and if you want to achieve it use validations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Use this, I have modified your code..

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton ourButton;
    private EditText operand1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find Views by IDs :
        ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
        operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

        ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

        String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString().trim();

        if(ed_text.equals(""))
        {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else
        {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
         }
      }
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not checking the value in the listener. Change it to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find Views by IDs :
    ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);


    ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (operand1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also onCreate gets called when the Activity is created so you can't check the name field's value in there. That's why you need to move that check in your button's click listener. Then it will always check if the name field is empty when you click your button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the check when the button is pressed, here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton ourButton;
private EditText operand1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find Views by IDs :
    ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

    ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(operand1.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You guys overwhelmed in just couple of minutes, thanks this worked.

Comment: I hope you check the first correct answer among all of these... ;)

Comment: Also in this answer one space is considered as valid username

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private ImageButton ourButton;
     private EditText operand1;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          // Find Views by IDs :
          ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
          operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

          String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString().trim();

          ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if(ed_text.isEmpty() || ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              } else {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);       
              } 
         });
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageButton ourButton;
private EditText operand1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find Views by IDs :
    ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
    ourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.gobutton) {
       if(operand1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a  username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }else{
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,ScreenName.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
       }

    } 
 }
```

Comment: You are missing trim() :)

Answer (score -1):

cahnge your code like that

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageButton ourButton;
private EditText operand1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Find Views by IDs :
ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

 ourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString().trim();
          if(ed_text.equals("")){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a  username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
             }else{

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     ScreenName.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton ourButton;
    private EditText operand1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find Views by IDs :
        ourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
        operand1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);

        String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString();

            ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
if(ed_text.equalsignorcase("")
        {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        else
        {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
            });


    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Don't set two OnClickListeners for one button**

Try following code -

```
         String ed_text = operand1.getText().toString().trim();
                    ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                           if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ed_text)){
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenName.class);
                               startActivity(myIntent);
                               finish();    //If you want to kill current Activity.

                             }else{
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              }
                        }
                    });
```

Hope it will help :)